# How can I finish all activities in current Android task?

Tags: android

Is it possible to finish all activities in current Android task?

Comment: Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600969/how-to-finish-series-of-open-sub-activities-from-one-activity) , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314838/android-how-to-detect-if-current-stack-of-activities-task-moves-to-background) , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825987/how-to-clear-all-activities-in-android-app) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities)

Answer (score 3):

It was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities).
But basically there's no such function... Maybe you could keep a collection of all the activities and finish them yourself, but I doubt that's good practice.
Or if all your activities are in the same "stack" you could try the answer given by "user370305".

Comment: Yep. I know that there are similar questions. However there is still no answer. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP doesn't solve problem, however it is marked there as answer

Comment: That's true, so if you really want close all activities you'll have to create some sort of task manager that tracks all activities and create a loop to finish them all. Btw, I think [this](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html) is an interesting blog post about an exit button in android apps (as I think that's what you're aiming for :)).

Answer (score -1):

There is another alternative. Whole application could be done using fragments with single activity. FragmentManager provide full control over fragments and it is possible to finish all of them.